# What's the difference between GCC builtin vectorization types and C arrays?

Tags: gcc, assembly, sse, vectorization

I have three functions `a()`, `b()` and `c()` that are supposed to do the same thing:

```
typedef float Builtin __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));

typedef struct {
        float values[4];
} Struct;

typedef union {
        Builtin b;
        Struct s;
} Union;

extern void printv(Builtin);
extern void printv(Union);
extern void printv(Struct);

int a() {
        Builtin m = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };
        printv(m);
}

int b() {
        Union m = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };
        printv(m);
}

int c() {
        Struct m = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };
        printv(m);
}
```

When I compile this code I observe the following behaviour:

- When calling `printv()` in `a()` all 4 floats are being passed by `%xmm0`. No writes to memory occur.
- When calling `printv()` in `b()` 2 floats are being passed by `%xmm0` and the two other floats by `%xmm1`. To accomplish this 4 floats are loaded (.LC0) to `%xmm2` and from there to memory. After that, 2 floats are read from the same place in memory to `%xmm0` and the 2 other floats are loaded (.LC1) to `%xmm1`.
- I'm a bit lost on what `c()` actually does.

Why are `a()`, `b()` and `c()` different?

Here is the assembly output for a():

```
        vmovaps .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
        call    _Z6printvU8__vectorf
```

The assembly output for b():

```
        vmovaps .LC0(%rip), %xmm2
        vmovaps %xmm2, (%rsp)
        vmovq   .LC1(%rip), %xmm1
        vmovq   (%rsp), %xmm0
        call    _Z6printv5Union
```

And the assembly output for c():

```
         andq    $-32, %rsp
         subq    $32, %rsp
         vmovaps .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
         vmovaps %xmm0, (%rsp)
         vmovq   .LC2(%rip), %xmm0
         vmovq   8(%rsp), %xmm1
         call    _Z6printv6Struct
```

The data:

```
        .section        .rodata.cst16,"aM",@progbits,16
        .align 16
.LC0:
        .long   1065353216
        .long   1073741824
        .long   1077936128
        .long   1082130432
        .section        .rodata.cst8,"aM",@progbits,8
        .align 8
.LC1:
        .quad   4647714816524288000
        .align 8
.LC2:
        .quad   4611686019492741120
```

The quad `4647714816524288000` seems to be nothing more than the floats `3.0` and `4.0` in adjacent long words.

Comment: Looks like this is an issue with the calling convention. `__m128` can be passed in directly by register. But `Packed` must be passed with the parameter split across `xmm0` and `xmm1`. In short, the calling convention probably prevents the compiler from doing such an optimization.

Comment: I edited the question quite a bit since you posted your comment. I replaced all AVX-related stuff with the GCC builtin types I found in the header files to make the question much more understandable. But I think you might be right about the calling conventions. But why?

Answer (score 1):

Nice question, I had to dig a little because I never used [SSE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Streaming_SIMD_Extensions) (in this case SSE2) myself. Essentially vector instructions are used to operate on **multiple** values stored in **one** register i.e. the XMM(0-7) registers. In C the data type float uses [IEEE 754](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format) and its length is thus 32bits. Using four floats will yield a vector of length 128bits which is exactly the length of the XMM(0-7) registers. Now the registers provided by SSE look like this:

```
SSE (avx-128):                         |----------------|name: XMM0; size: 128bit
SSE (avx-256):        |----------------|----------------|name: YMM0; size: 256bit
```

In your first case `a()` you use the SIMD vectorization with

```
typedef float Builtin __attribute__ ((vector_size (16)));
```

which allows you to shift the entire vector in one go into the XMM0 register. Now in your second case `b()` you use a union. But because you do not load .LC0 into the union with `Union m.b = { 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0 };` the data is not recognized as a vectorization. This leads to the following behavior:

The data from .LC0 is loaded into XMM2 with:

```
 vmovaps .LC0(%rip), %xmm2
```

but because your data can be interpreted as a *structure* **or** as a *vectorization* the data has to be split up into two 64bit chunks which will still have to be in the XMM(0-7) registers because it can be treated as a vectorization but it has to be maximally 64bit long that it can be transferred to a register (which is only 64bit wide and would overflow if 128bit were transferred to it; data is lost) because the data can also be treated as a structure. This is done in the following.

The vectorization in XMM2 is loaded to memory with

```
    vmovaps %xmm2, (%rsp)
```

now the upper 64bits of the vectorization (bits 64-127), i.e. the floats `3.0` and `4.0` are moved (vmovq moves quadword i.e. 64 bits ) to XMM1 with

```
    vmovq   .LC1(%rip), %xmm1
```

and finally the lower 64bits of the vectorization (bits 0-63) i.e. the floats `1.0` and `2.0` are moved from memory to XMM0 with

```
    vmovq   (%rsp), %xmm0
```

Now you have the upper and the lower part of the 128bit vector in separate XMM(0-7) registers.

Now in case `c()` I'm not quite sure as well but here it goes. First %rsp is aligned to a 32bit address and then 32 byte are subtracted to store the data on the stack (this will align to a 32bit address again) this is done with

```
     andq    $-32, %rsp
     subq    $32, %rsp
```

now this time the vectorization is loaded into XMM0 and then placed on the stack with

```
     vmovaps .LC0(%rip), %xmm0
     vmovaps %xmm0, (%rsp)
```

and finally the upper 64bits of the vectorization are stored in XMM0 and the lower 64bits are stored in the XMM1 register with

```
     vmovq   .LC2(%rip), %xmm0
     vmovq   8(%rsp), %xmm1
```

In all three cases the vectorization is treated differently. Hope this helps.

Comment: That is pretty much what I observed. I'd really like to know why GCC treats the three cases differently. I can't really see any difference, at least semantically.

Comment: You point out that "it has to be maximally 64bit long that it can be transferred to a register". Why is that?

Comment: Your processor is 64bit i.e. registers are 64bit wide, only XMM0-7 are wider. I think case (b) shows this quite well. The data is stored differently from case (a) because the data, _due to the union_, can be interpreted as a **vectorization** or a **structure**.